# java static access in a non-static way

Tags: java, static

I've got my IRC Bot running with some games. I tried to separate all the code into different classes.

One of these is my roulette game below:

```
if (message.equalsIgnoreCase("!spin")) { 
    if(Games.randomNumber(5) == 1){
        rroulette = sender;
        Games.russianroulettefail(channel);
    }else{
        rroulette = sender;
        Games.russianroulettewin(channel);
    }
}
```

My Game class extends `MyBot` so I can access all the Strings I need.

```
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
/// Russisch Roulette Generator (fail)
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////    
public static void russianroulettefail(String channel){
    rngroulette = randomNumber(1);
    switch(rngroulette){
       case 0:
            if(englishmode == true){
                sendMessage(channel, rroulette+" Aims towards his Head and pulls the Trigger... PENG. "+rroulette+" Shot himself. RIP");
            }else{
           sendMessage(channel,""+rroulette+" richtet den Revolver auf seinen Kopf und drückt ab.... PENG!!! Der Schuss löst sich und die Menge ist geschockt!  R.I.P "+rroulette+"");
            }//sendMessage(channel,"/timeout "+rroulette+"");
            if(englishmode == true){
                sendMessage(channel, rroulette+" Lost 100 "+coinname+"");
            }else{
           sendMessage(channel, rroulette+" Verliert 100 "+coinname+"");
            }

            int coinanzahl = 0;

        try {
            coinanzahl = MySQLAccess.getcoins(rroulette);
        } catch (Exception e1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }

            int newtotalcoins;
            newtotalcoins = coinanzahl-100;

        try {
            MySQLAccess.setcoins(rroulette, newtotalcoins);
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

           rroulette = null;
        break;
 }
 }
```

I get this error:

> Cannot make a static reference to the non-static method russianroulettewin(String) from the type Games

but as soon as I set the method to static I get the errors in the game class:

> Cannot make a static reference to the non-static method sendMessage(String, String) from the type PircBot

Are there any workarounds for this?

Comment: Look in the `Related` section.

Comment: what? i dont understand.

Comment: Please post more code.

Comment: The `Related` section to the right of your screen has related question. Do some research.

Comment: @user3220962 On the right side of this page, underneath the ads, there is a list titles "Related".

Comment: Sorry, user3220962 i should have read the question properly (just deleted my answer)

Answer (score 1):

You have two options:

- Make all your methods static, or
- Instantiate the class that contains `russianroulettefail`. *Note: `russianroulettefail` should be capitalized like `russianRouletteFail`.*

The latter option is probably the conventional one, but the former is easier. I suggest that for now, put `static` before all your method and variable declarations. To prepare for the future, you should read a good tutorial on classes and OOP (Object Oriented Programming) like the one here: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/objects.html.

Comment: What exactly means "Instantiate"? =)

Comment: @user3220962 Create a new instance of, i.e. `MyClass myClass = new MyClass()`. You can then access all of `MyClass`'s non-static method like: `myClass.method();`.

Comment: Well, The Errors are gone atleast. Now just something else appeared: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StackOverflowError whats wront there?  and it points to public class Games extends MyBot{

Comment: @user3220962 [Ask another question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). Make sure to include the full stack trace and _all_ the relevant code.